# Performing calculations based on dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables.

- Accounts(account_number*,balance)
- Transactions(account_number*,transaction_number*,date,amount,type)

Date is the date that the transaction happened. Amount is the amount of the transaction
and it can have a positive or a negative value, dependent of the type(Withdrawal -,Deposit +). I think the type is irrelevant here as the amount is already given in the proper way. 
I need to write a query which points out the account_number of the accounts that have at least once had negative balance.

Here's some sample data from the Transactions table, ordered by account_number and date.

```
account_number  transaction_number      date    amount  type
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1               2                   02/03/2013  -20000  withdrawal
1               3                   03/15/2013  300     deposit
1               1                   01/01/2013  100     deposit
2               1                   04/15/2013  235236  deposit
3               1                   06/15/2013  500     deposit
4               1                   03/01/2013  10      deposit
4               2                   04/01/2013  80      deposit
5               1                   11/11/2013  10000   deposit
5               2                   12/11/2013  20000   deposit
5               3                   12/13/2013  -10002  withdrawal
6               1                   03/15/2013  102300  deposit
7               1                   03/15/2013  100     deposit
8               1                   08/08/2013  133990  deposit
9               1                   05/09/2013  10000   deposit
9               2                   06/01/2013  300     deposit
9               3                   10/11/2013  23      deposit
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this with an analytic to keep a running balance for an account:

```
SELECT DISTINCT account_number
  FROM ( SELECT account_number
           ,SUM(amount)
                      OVER (PARTITION BY account_number ORDER BY date) AS running_balance
       FROM transactions
       ) x
  WHERE running_balance < 0
```

Explanation:

It is using an analytic function: the `PARTITION BY` breaks the table into groups identified by the account number. Within each group, the data is ordered by `date`. Then there is a walk through each element in the ordered group and the `SUM` function is applied (by default summing everything from the beginning of the group to the current row).  This gives you a running balance.  Just run the inner query on its own and take a look at the output, then read a bit about analytic queries.  They are pretty cool.

Comment: I really don't get what this is doing, but I do not think the amount should be converter to negative as the table data is already like that. If the type is deposit, the amount is positive and if the type is withdrawal, the amount is negative.

Comment: If the `type` has no meaning since it is implicit by the sign of the amount, then the query can be simplified to `SUM(amount) OVER ...`

Comment: Yes, that is right. I've tested your query on a couple of ways and it looks like it works, but I don't get what it does exactly. I would be grateful if you can please explain a little bit in detail. Thank you anyway. Sorry I can't vote up I do not have sufficient reputation

Comment: I would like to ask you one more thing. How can i point out the account number and transaction number of a transaction that lead from a positive to negative balance?

Comment: Run the inner query adding in the transaction number: `SELECT account_number, transaction_number, SUM(amount) ...` and look at the results. You will then want the outer query to look for the negative running totals. I won't have time to poke at it now, if there are questions, you might be best off to post another question.